# WPF scrollbar on Auto and SizeToContent="Height" goes under Windows7 toolbar

Tags: wpf, windows-7, scrollbar

I have peculiar problem where WPF scrollbar set to `Auto` and `Window` set to `SizeToContent="Height"` sizes itself to go under the Windows 7 toolbar.

[image]

XAML is trivial really.

```
<Window x:Class="....ProbateControllerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Probate" Width="1100" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Background="White" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <StackPanel>
                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I could add `Height` and set to `SizeToContent="Manual"` as constant to `Window` but when on lower resolution I will run into same issue.
I am sure someone by now has ran into this problem and I must be missing something here.

Comment: You want to use SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height

Comment: you don't need the grid as a root element, since it does nothing. Similarly you don't need StackPanel. Also you don't need ContentControl, because ScrolViewer is ContentControl. To center Content use HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the MaxHeight of the `Window` to `SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight` in the constructor of the window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

Oddy, for me, the window still hides slightly behind the taskbar, but with an adjustment of 20 it looks fine.

```
this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight-20;
```

I've tried this on various operating systems and screen resolutions, and the adjustment of 20 seems to work well on Windows 7/8. On XP etc, the adjustment is unnecessary, so you end up with the window being slightly smaller than the screen height. I guess if that's a problem you could detect the OS version and apply the adjustment if necessary.

If you didn't need to apply an adjustment, you can define this in the xaml:

```
MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeightKey}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to solve that issue just using the XAML markup.

Other answers consider `SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight` or `SystemParameters.WorkArea`, so taking into account only the primary screen. But what happens if this window will be shown on a secondary screen with different screen resolution?

I would suggest you to use a small P/Invoke code snippet to find out the screen  the window will be displayed on.

We will need two WinAPI functions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MONITORINFO lpmi);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);
```

They use WinAPI native data structures and constants that are missing in .NET, so we have to define them too:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MONITORINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public RECT rcMonitor, rcWork;
    public uint dwFlags;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

const int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2;
```

In your windows's constructor, subscribe to the `SourceInitialized` event. This event will be raised when the underlying Win32 window will be created and initialized.

```
public Window1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.SourceInitialized += Window1_SourceInitialized;         
}
```

In that event handler, just set the `MaxHeight` property of your window according to the screen working area (that is - excluding the task bar).

```
void Window1_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First, get the window handle
    IntPtr hwnd = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;

    // Obtain the screen the windows will be displayed on
    IntPtr hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

    // If we've got the monitor...
    if (hMonitor != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MONITORINFO mi = new MONITORINFO();
        mi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mi);

        // ...and the monitor information, then we set the size constraint
        if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, ref mi))
        {
            this.MaxHeight = mi.rcWork.Bottom - mi.rcWork.Top;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you wish, you could subscribe to the window's `LocationChanged` event, where you could change your windows's maximum height according to screen resolution of the screen this window is currently displayed on. However, that could be somewhat difficult: what happens if the window will be displayed on multiple screens simultaneously (especially when they all have different screen resolutions)?

Comment: what about `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens` ?
you can get working area of all windows and then it should be easy to find out on which screen is windows currently positioned. Nevermind it's windows forms namespace.

Answer (score 1):

what about this? It will turn of SizeToContent and maximize window if it overflows screen:

```
    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActualHeight > SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight)
        {
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Height;
        }
    }
```

- if this is not acceptable, use Gary Wright solution. I don't reccoment you to use those Win32 API, since there is no guarantee it will work on different system, e.g. Windows 10
- if you have multiple monitors with different height, you can "show" transparent maximized window measure it (ActualHeight property) to get the workspace size

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove the "SizeToContent" attribute, since it will size the window to fit its content.

Why you have to specify it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer. The problem the author is facing is as expected since the "SizeToContent" attribute produces exactly this behavior.